# Unit testing a method blocks indefinitely on CompletableFuture.join()

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, completable-future

I want to use some async `CompletionStage` operations in a business logic method, using the methods from the `CompletableFuture` class. The chained calls are:

```
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> firstOperation(), executor)
                        .thenRunAsync(() -> secondOperation(), executor)
                        .thenApplyAsync(none -> new MessageDTO("OK"), executor)
                        .join();
```

While writing the unit tests for the method which ends with the above snippet, I have noticed that the unit test is blocking indefinitely. I have tried several approaches to circumvent/avoid the blocking ([this](https://dzone.com/articles/workaround-multi-threaded) is one of them, `@Mock`-ing and `@Spy`-ing the `Executor` object), but to no avail.

There are several aspects which elude me:

- where is the blocking coming from? is it from the `CompletableFuture` class or from Mockito?
- why is it only blocking in the unit test and not in the service method?

---

Used libraries:

- Spring Boot v2.1.2 & Spring Framework v5.1.4
- Mockito v2.23
- JUnit Jupiter v5.3.2

Comment: Is any of tasks running (for example... does `firstOperation()`/`secondOperation()` get called? Where is it stuck?

Comment: @ernest_k - the curious thing is that the blocking is done _before_ any of them gets called.